# What are Mori and Honey doing?

Tags: ouran-high-school-host-club

In the episode *The Sun, The Sea and the Host Club*. Honey-senpai and Mori-senpai are doing something with a couple of the girls in the background while Haruhi is under the umbrella complaining about the situation.

What is it that they are doing, and why does Haruhi act the way she does when she sees it? Does it have something to do with the class divide between her and the rest of the host club?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's supposed to be some sort of [Kachāshī](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kach%C4%81sh%C4%AB), a form of traditional Okinawan dance. They were on the beach in Okinawa but the dancing is wrong, which may be why Haruhi is going "???" at them.

For reference, here's the screenshot of the scene in question:

[image]

And some screenshots of the Okinawan dance:

[image]

[image]

[image]